# Call a function that is specifically not templated

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a bunch of functions that check for collisions between various types of shape.

```
bool Collides(Rect r, Circle c);
bool Collides(Rect r, Line l);
bool Collides(Line l, Circle c);
```

I was hoping I could implement a single templated function that could halve my implementation count by allowing it to swap the input parameters. So that instead of also having to implement:

```
// The same as before but the input parameters swapped
bool Collides(Circle c, Rect r) { return Collides(r, c); }
bool Collides(Line l, Rect r) { return Collides(r, l); }
bool Collides(Circle c, Line l) { return Collides(l, c); }
```

I could instead write this once:

```
template <typename Shape1, typename Shape2>
bool Collides(Shape1 a, Shape2 b)
{
    return Collides(b, a);
}
```

Unfortunately when both `Collides(a, b)` an `Collides(b, a)` are unimplemented it calls the templated function recursively at runtime, which is obviously unintended behaviour.

Is there some C++ tag or feature that allows you to turn off or disallow argument type deduction for a specified line or block? The intent would be to force the compiler to look for a non-templated implementation then fail to compile if one didn't exist.

Comment: @royseph The template function even is not selected when there is a non-template function with the same name and suitable parameter types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One time that a function template is not looked up is during the declaration of the function (Before the opening `{`). Taking advantage of that, we can SFINAE unimplemented arguments out:

```cpp
template<typename Shape1, typename Shape2>
auto Collides(Shape1 a, Shape2 b) -> decltype(::Collides(b, a)) {
    return Collides(b, a);
}
```

Though note that this must be written after all the other declarations of `Collides`.

---

You can also just call a different function that delegates:

```cpp
template<typename Shape1, typename Shape2>
auto ActualCollides(Shape1 a, Shape2 b) -> decltype(Collides(a, b)) {
    return Collides(a, b);
}

template<typename Shape1, typename Shape2>
auto ActualCollides(Shape1 a, Shape2 b) -> decltype(Collides(b, a)) {
    return Collides(b, a);
}

// Or rename `Collides` into `CollidesImpl` and you can call this `Collides` instead
```

Which will take into account future `Collides` functions because of ADL.

Comment: So let me get this straight, beause the `auto` and `->` the function hasn't actually been declared by the time we reach the `return` statement, so it cannot therefore be called recursively?

Comment: @Troyseph In the body, the template is part of the viable functions that could be called, but non-template functions are always a better match so it will be called. However, we will never get to the body if there is no other match.

Comment: @Artyer very neat, so what exactly is the return type? It looks like it is a function? Or am I misunderstanding the usage of `decltype`

Comment: The return type is "whatever `Collides(b, a)` returns".

Comment: Ah I understand! If there isn't a function `Collides(b, a)` the compiler cannot deduce the return type of the template and compilation fails, and the compiler cannot use an `auto` return type to work out the type, so it cannot use itself to define its return type either.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to remove function templates from the overload set. In your particular case there are workarounds, such as:

```
struct CollidesImpl {
    bool operator()(Rect r, Circle c);
    bool operator()(Rect r, Line l);
    bool operator()(Line l, Circle c);
};

template <typename Shape1, typename Shape2>
bool Collides(Shape1 a, Shape2 b)
{
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<CollidesImpl, Shape1, Shape2> ||
                  std::is_invocable_v<CollidesImpl, Shape2, Shape1>,
                  "No implementation exists for these argument types");
    if constexpr(std::is_invocable_v<CollidesImpl, Shape1, Shape2>) {
        return CollidesImpl{}(a, b);
    } else {
        return CollidesImpl{}(b, a);
    }
}
```